# Why does `apt-get install python-` remove everything?

Tags: apt, package-management

Have a look at the output of this simulated `apt-get`:

```
$ apt-get -s install python-
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcj-4.6-base libc-ares-dev libev-dev libev4 libgc1c3 libgconf2-doc libgio-cil libgsl0ldbl libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore liblapack3
  libmagick++5 libmlt++3 libmlt-data libmlt5 libportmidi0 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libsexy2 libsmpeg0 libsox-fmt-alsa libsox-fmt-base
  libsox2 libtorrent-rasterbar7 libv8-3.8.9.20 libv8-dev melt node-abbrev node-block-stream node-fstream node-graceful-fs node-inherits
  node-ini node-lru-cache node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-node-uuid node-nopt node-request node-rimraf node-semver node-tar node-which
  nodejs python-matplotlib-data python3-dirspec recordmydesktop ubuntuone-client-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  apt-xapian-index bzr bzr-dbus bzrtools clang clang-3.2 compiler-rt covergloobus cython deluge deluge-common deluge-console deluge-gtk
  deluged dput duplicity fail2ban gcj-4.6-jre-lib gconf-editor gconf2 gimp gimp-ufraw git-cola gksu gstreamer0.10-gconf gtk-recordmydesktop
  hugin hugin-data hugin-tools inkscape ipython jockey-common jockey-kde kde-config-touchpad kubuntu-firefox-installer
  kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-settings-netbook landscape-client-ui-install libbonoboui2-0
  libgcj-common libgcj12 libgconf2-dev libgksu2-0 libglade2-dev libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common
  libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libpurple-bin meld muon muon-installer muon-notifier nmap nodejs-dev
  npm nvidia-settings-313 openshot openstv pastebinit pdftk picard plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook playonlinux
  printer-driver-sag-gdi pylint python python-all python-all-dev python-appindicator python-apport python-apt python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon-gtk python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets python-boto python-bzrlib python-cairo python-central
  python-chardet python-configglue python-configobj python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dateutil python-dbus python-debian
  python-debtagshw python-decorator python-defer python-dev python-dirspec python-distutils-extra python-django python-egenix-mxdatetime
  python-egenix-mxtools python-enchant python-fixtures python-gamin python-gconf python-gdbm python-gi python-gi-cairo python-glade2
  python-gnome2 python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gobject-2-dev python-gpgme python-gst0.10
  python-gtk2 python-gtk2-doc python-gtksourceview2 python-httplib2 python-ibus python-imaging python-imaging-compat python-indicate
  python-jsonrpc2 python-kde4 python-keybinder python-keyring python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-libproxy
  python-libtorrent python-libxml2 python-logilab-astng python-logilab-common python-lxml python-matplotlib python-memcache python-mlt5
  python-mutagen python-nose python-notify python-numpy python-oauth python-oauthlib python-opengl python-openssl python-pam python-paramiko
  python-pexpect python-pip python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pyatspi
  python-pyatspi2 python-pyaudio python-pycurl python-pygame python-pygoocanvas python-pyinotify python-pyorbit python-pyparsing
  python-pyrex python-pytools python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-quickly-common python-quickly-core python-quickly.widgets
  python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-requests python-serial python-setuptools python-simplegeneric
  python-simplejson python-sip python-six python-smbc python-software-properties python-support python-telepathy python-testtools python-tk
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web python-tz python-ubuntuone-client
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uniconvertor python-uno python-urllib3 python-virtkey python-vte python-wadllib python-webkit
  python-wimpiggy python-wnck python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion python-xapian python-xdg python-xkit python-xlib python-yaml python-zeitgeist
  python-zope.interface quickly quickly-widgets rastertosag-gdi screen-resolution-extra ssh-import-id steam:i386 steam-launcher stgit
  sublime-text sublime-text-2-beta system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev terminator ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-couch ufraw update-notifier-common userconfig xchat xchat-common xchat-indicator xpra zeitgeist
  zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 244 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Remv kubuntu-firefox-installer [13.04ubuntu2]
Remv muon-installer [2.0.0-0ubuntu3.1]
Remv muon [2.0.0-0ubuntu3.1]
Remv apt-xapian-index [0.45ubuntu2]
Remv bzr-dbus [0.1~bzr53-0buntu1]
Remv bzrtools [2.5+bzr786-2ubuntu1]
Remv bzr [2.6.0~bzr6571-4ubuntu2]
Remv clang [3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1]
Remv clang-3.2 [3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1]
Remv compiler-rt [3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1]
Remv covergloobus [1.7-0~361~precise1]
Remv cython [0.17.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv deluge [1.3.6-0ubuntu2]
Remv deluged [1.3.6-0ubuntu2]
Remv deluge-gtk [1.3.6-0ubuntu2]
Remv deluge-console [1.3.6-0ubuntu2]
Remv deluge-common [1.3.6-0ubuntu2]
Remv dput [0.9.6.3+nmu1ubuntu1]
Remv duplicity [0.6.21-0ubuntu1]
Remv fail2ban [0.8.7.1-1]
Remv gcj-4.6-jre-lib [4.6.4-1ubuntu1]
Remv gconf-editor [3.0.1-1ubuntu2]
Remv xchat-indicator [0.3.11-0ubuntu4]
Remv xchat [2.8.8-7ubuntu2]
Remv xchat-common [2.8.8-7ubuntu2]
Remv ufraw [0.19.2-0ubuntu1]
Remv terminator [0.96-2fakesync1]
Remv libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 [3.0.0-1ubuntu1]
Remv libgnomevfs2-extra [1:2.24.4-1ubuntu5]
Remv python-gnome2 [2.28.1+dfsg-1build1]
Remv libgnomeui-0 [2.24.5-2ubuntu3]
Remv libbonoboui2-0 [2.24.5-0ubuntu2]
Remv libgnome2-0 [2.32.1-2ubuntu4] [libgnome2-bin:amd64 ]
Remv libgnome2-bin [2.32.1-2ubuntu4]
Remv inkscape [0.48.4-0.1ubuntu2]
Remv libgnomevfs2-0 [1:2.24.4-1ubuntu5]
Remv libgnomevfs2-common [1:2.24.4-1ubuntu5]
Remv libgnome2-common [2.32.1-2ubuntu4]
Remv gksu [2.0.2-6ubuntu2]
Remv libgksu2-0 [2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu2]
Remv libgconf2-dev [3.2.6-0ubuntu1]
Remv gstreamer0.10-gconf [0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu2]
Remv gconf2 [3.2.6-0ubuntu1]
Remv gimp-ufraw [0.19.2-0ubuntu1]
Remv gimp [2.8.4-1ubuntu1]
Remv git-cola [1.8.1-1]
Remv gtk-recordmydesktop [0.3.8-4.1ubuntu1]
Remv hugin [2011.4.0+dfsg-5ubuntu2]
Remv hugin-tools [2011.4.0+dfsg-5ubuntu2]
Remv hugin-data [2011.4.0+dfsg-5ubuntu2]
Remv ipython [0.13.2-1]
Remv steam:i386 [1.0.0.36]
Remv steam-launcher [1.0.0.36]
Remv jockey-kde [0.9.7-0ubuntu13]
Remv jockey-common [0.9.7-0ubuntu13]
Remv kde-config-touchpad [0.8.1-1ubuntu3]
Remv kubuntu-netbook-default-settings [1:13.04ubuntu11]
Remv kubuntu-settings-netbook [1:13.04ubuntu11]
Remv kubuntu-settings-desktop [1:13.04ubuntu11]
Remv landscape-client-ui-install [12.12-0ubuntu3]
Remv pdftk [1.44-7]
Remv libgcj12 [4.6.4-1ubuntu1]
Remv libgcj-common [1:4.7.3-1ubuntu10]
Remv libglade2-dev [1:2.6.4-1ubuntu2]
Remv libpurple-bin [1:2.10.7-0ubuntu4.1]
Remv meld [1.6.1-1]
Remv muon-notifier [2.0.0-0ubuntu3.1]
Remv nmap [6.00-0.3]
Remv npm [1.1.4~dfsg-2]
Remv nodejs-dev [0.6.19~dfsg1-5ubuntu1]
Remv nvidia-settings-313 [313.30-0ubuntu1~xedgers~quantal1]
Remv openshot [1.4.3-1]
Remv openstv [1.6.1-1]
Remv pastebinit [1.3-4ubuntu1]
Remv picard [1.1-0ubuntu3]
Remv plasma-widget-facebook [1.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv plasma-scriptengine-python [4:4.10.2-0ubuntu2]
Remv playonlinux [4.1.8]
Remv rastertosag-gdi [0.1-3]
Remv printer-driver-sag-gdi [0.1-3]
Remv pylint [0.26.0-1ubuntu1]
Remv sublime-text-2-beta [2.0.1-1~webupd8~quantal]
Remv sublime-text [2.0.1-1~webupd8~quantal]
Remv xpra [0.3.11+dfsg-1]
Remv userconfig [0.9.0-0ubuntu11]
Remv ubuntuone-couch [0.3.0-0ubuntu5]
Remv stgit [0.15-1.1]
Remv quickly [12.08.1-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-xlib [0.14+20091101-1]
Remv python-wxgtk2.8 [2.8.12.1-11ubuntu4]
Remv python-wxversion [2.8.12.1-11ubuntu4]
Remv python-wimpiggy [0.3.11+dfsg-1]
Remv python-virtkey [0.63.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-uno [1:4.0.2-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-telepathy [0.15.19-2.1build1]
Remv python-matplotlib [1.2.1-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-gamin [0.1.10-4.1]
Remv python-support [1.0.15]
Remv python-software-properties [0.92.17]
Remv python-simplegeneric [0.8.1-1]
Remv quickly-widgets [12.03]
Remv python-quickly.widgets [12.03]
Remv python-quickly-core [12.08.1-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-quickly-common [12.08.1-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-pytools [2011.5-2]
Remv python-pygame [1.9.1release+dfsg-8]
Remv python-pyaudio [0.2.7-1]
Remv python-pyatspi2 [2.7.91+dfsg-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-pyatspi [2.7.91+dfsg-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-pip [1.3.1-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-opengl [3.0.1-1]
Remv python-mlt5 [0.8.8-1]
Remv python-libtorrent [0.16.7-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-libproxy [0.4.11-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-keybinder [0.3.0-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-kde4 [4:4.10.2-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-jsonrpc2 [0.3.2-3]
Remv python-indicate [12.10.1-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-gtksourceview2 [2.10.1-2build1]
Remv python-gnupginterface [0.3.2-9.1ubuntu3]
Remv python-enchant [1.6.5-2build1]
Remv python-central [0.6.17ubuntu2]
Remv python-aptdaemon-gtk [1.0-0ubuntu9]
Remv python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets [1.0-0ubuntu9]
Remv ttf-mscorefonts-installer [3.4+nmu1ubuntu1]
Remv update-notifier-common [0.134]
Remv ubuntu-system-service [0.2.4]
Remv ssh-import-id [3.14-0ubuntu1]
Remv screen-resolution-extra [0.15ubuntu1]
Remv python-ubuntuone-client [4.2.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol [4.2.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-twisted-web [12.3.0-1]
Remv python-twisted-names [12.3.0-1]
Remv python-twisted-core [12.3.0-1ubuntu6]
Remv python-launchpadlib [1.10.2+ds-1]
Remv python-lazr.restfulclient [0.13.1-1]
Remv python-zope.interface [4.0.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv zeitgeist [0.9.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv zeitgeist-datahub [0.9.5-1ubuntu1]
Remv zeitgeist-core [0.9.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-zeitgeist [0.9.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-yaml [3.10-4build2]
Remv python-xkit [0.5.0ubuntu1]
Remv python-configglue [1.0-1build1]
Remv python-xdg [0.25-2]
Remv python-xapian [1.2.12-2]
Remv python-wnck [2.32.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1]
Remv python-webkit [1.1.8-2ubuntu4]
Remv python-wadllib [1.3.2-1]
Remv python-vte [1:0.28.2-5ubuntu1]
Remv python-requests [1.1.0-1]
Remv python-urllib3 [1.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-uniconvertor [1.1.4-1ubuntu2]
Remv python-tz [2012c-1]
Remv python-twisted-bin [12.3.0-1ubuntu6]
Remv python-tk [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-fixtures [0.3.12-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-testtools [0.9.24-0ubuntu2]
Remv system-config-printer-common [1.3.12+20130308-0ubuntu4]
Remv python-smbc [1.0.13-0ubuntu4]
Remv python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets [1.0-0ubuntu9]
Remv python-aptdaemon [1.0-0ubuntu9]
Remv python-debian [0.1.21+nmu2ubuntu1]
Remv python-six [1.2.0-1]
Remv python-qt4 [4.10-0ubuntu3]
Remv python-sip [4.14.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-simplejson [2.6.2-1]
Remv python-setuptools [0.6.34-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-serial [2.6-1]
Remv python-reportlab-accel [2.6-1]
Remv python-reportlab [2.6-1]
Remv python-renderpm [2.6-1]
Remv python-qt4-dbus [4.10-0ubuntu3]
Remv python-pyudev [0.16.1-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-pyrex [0.9.8.5-2ubuntu2]
Remv python-pyparsing [1.5.7+dfsg1-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-pyorbit [2.24.0-6ubuntu3]
Remv python-pyinotify [0.9.3-1.1ubuntu1]
Remv python-pygoocanvas [0.14.1-1ubuntu8]
Remv system-config-printer-udev [1.3.12+20130308-0ubuntu4]
Remv python-cupshelpers [1.3.12+20130308-0ubuntu4]
Remv python-pycurl [7.19.0-5ubuntu8]
Remv python-protobuf [2.4.1-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-apport [2.9.2-0ubuntu8]
Remv python-problem-report [2.9.2-0ubuntu8]
Remv python-nose [1.1.2-3ubuntu4]
Remv python-lazr.uri [1.0.3-1]
Remv python-pkg-resources [0.6.34-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-piston-mini-client [0.7.5-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-pexpect [2.4-1]
Remv python-paramiko [1.7.7.1-3.1ubuntu1]
Remv python-pam [0.4.2-13ubuntu4]
Remv python-openssl [0.13-2ubuntu3]
Remv python-oauthlib [0.3.7-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-oauth [1.0.1-3build1]
Remv python-numpy [1:1.7.1-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-notify [0.1.1-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-mutagen [1.20-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-memcache [1.48-1]
Remv python-lxml [3.1.0-1]
Remv python-logilab-astng [0.24.1-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-logilab-common [0.58.3-1ubuntu1]
Remv python-gst0.10 [0.10.22-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-libxml2 [2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4]
Remv python-keyring [0.9.2-1ubuntu2]
Remv python-imaging-compat [1.1.7+2.0.0-1] [python-imaging:amd64 ]
Remv python-imaging [1.1.7+2.0.0-1]
Remv python-ibus [1.4.2-0ubuntu2]
Remv python-httplib2 [0.7.7-1]
Remv python-gtk2-doc [2.24.0-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-gnomekeyring [2.32.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1]
Remv python-glade2 [2.24.0-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-gtk2 [2.24.0-3ubuntu1]
Remv python-gpgme [0.3-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-gobject-2-dev [2.28.6-11]
Remv python-appindicator [12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-gobject [3.8.0-2]
Remv python-gconf [2.28.1+dfsg-1build1]
Remv python-gobject-2 [2.28.6-11]
Remv python-gi-cairo [3.8.0-2]
Remv python-gi [3.8.0-2]
Remv python-gdbm [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-egenix-mxdatetime [3.2.5-1]
Remv python-egenix-mxtools [3.2.5-1]
Remv python-django [1.4.5-1]
Remv python-distutils-extra [2.37-1]
Remv python-dirspec [4.2.0-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-all-dev [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-dev [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv python-defer [1.0.6-2]
Remv python-decorator [3.3.3-1]
Remv python-debtagshw [1.10.2ubuntu1]
Remv python-dbus [1.1.1-1ubuntu3]
Remv python-dateutil [1.5+dfsg-0.1]
Remv python-cups [1.9.62-0ubuntu3]
Remv python-crypto [2.6-4]
Remv python-bzrlib [2.6.0~bzr6571-4ubuntu2]
Remv python-configobj [4.7.2+ds-4]
Remv python-chardet [2.0.1-2build1]
Remv python-cairo [1.8.8-1ubuntu4]
Remv python-boto [2.3.0-1]
Remv python-apt [0.8.8ubuntu6]
Remv python-all [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
Remv python [2.7.4-0ubuntu1]
```

What is going on there? Why is it nuking the entire system?

Comment: Welp. [It's a feature of apt.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/214043/sudo-apt-get-install-foo-causes-removing-foo-package-and-everything-depends/214078#214078)

Comment: Now the question is... should we mark this a dupe and possibly end up with Oli's wrath.

Comment: I know when to call a banana a banana.